# Error loading YOLOv5 in opencv python, how to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, yolov5

I am trying to run people detection from above in opencv with YOLOv5, and I have problems with loading the model. My version of opencv is 4.6.0, and following the tutorial at [this link](https://learnopencv.com/object-detection-using-yolov5-and-opencv-dnn-in-c-and-python/#Object-Detection-using) I wrote this code

```
# hyper parameters
INPUT_WIDTH = 640  # width of the input for the YOLOv5 network
INPUT_HEIGHT = 640  # height of the  input for the YOLOv5 network
SCORE_THRESHOLD = 0.5  # filter low probability classes
NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.45  # remove overlapping bounding boxes (?)
CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.45  # filter low probability detection
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (255, 178, 50)
YELLOW = (0, 255, 255)
classes = []
person_found = False
# taking classes names
class_files = 'yolo/coco.names'
with open(class_files, 'r') as source:
classes = source.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')
# weights path
weights = 'yolo/models/yolov5s.onnx'
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights)
# parameters: image, scale factor, size in form of tuple, mean subtraction, swapRB
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, scalefactor=1/255, size=(INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT), mean=[0, 0, 0], swapRB=True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
outputs = net.forward(net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames())
```

but when I try to load the model I get this error:

```
[ERROR:0@1.622] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp (1021) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::ONNXImporter::handleNode DNN/ONNX: ERROR during processing node with 1 inputs and 1 outputs: [Identity]:(onnx_node!Identity_0) from domain='ai.onnx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Unitn\Corsi\Computer vision\project\synopsis\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    bg_frames = find_bg_frames(video, duration, fps)
  File "D:\Unitn\Corsi\Computer vision\project\synopsis\utils.py", line 152, in find_bg_frames
    people_found = find_people_with_yolo(frame)
  File "D:\Unitn\Corsi\Computer vision\project\synopsis\utils.py", line 102, in find_people_with_yolo
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(weights)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:1040: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::ONNXImporter::handleNode'
> Node [Identity@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!Identity_0) parse error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layer.cpp:246: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::Layer::getMemoryShapes'
>
```

Can anyone help me in finding the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Taking a close look at the `outputs` shape, it was found to be [1, 3, 80, 80, 85]. Whereas, it should be [25200x85] for default 640x640 onnx exports. It appears to be a buggy conversion from PyTorch to ONNX. In `yolov5s.onnx` model has been updated in the [article](https://learnopencv.com/object-detection-using-yolov5-and-opencv-dnn-in-c-and-python/).

Moreover, torch==1.12 has some bugs. Until it is fixed, please use torch==1.11 while converting the models.

Check out this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/239#issuecomment-1192562288).

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue, i solved it by adding "--simplify" for the Export

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`!python export.py --weights best.pt --simplify --opset 12 --include onnx`